# Bad background check

Tags: job-search

I am a licensed financial advisor and I can't get a job because I have a bad background check. Misdemeanors only. One conviction 30 years ago. Most recent 2012. What do I do?

Comment: _One conviction 30 years ago. Most recent 2012_?  Please clarify exactly how many misdemeanors?

Comment: Welcome to the site Mark. Unfortunately we can't really tell you what to do in your situation as [personal advice isn't a good fit for our Q&A format](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/#2695). It's not practical for us to answer a question that depends so heavily on your own abilities, preferences or circumstances. Instead, consider asking a factual question that will help you make your own choices, and that can be answered without detailed knowledge of your personal situation.

Comment: Also, you might look at [the 72 other questions tagged "background-check"](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background-check) - I am sure that your question has been asked somewhere there before.

Comment: I find it funny that 'stop committing crimes' is not a valid comment when he is asking what to do.  Go ahead and delete this one too, but that's the best advice he can get.

Comment: The last time I held a job as a financial advisor was June of 2015.

Comment: I left because I longer wanted to be a 1099 employee and thought I would find a job in banking easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am a licensed financial advisor and I can't get a job because I have
>   a bad background check. ... What do I do?

You *can* get a job.

The financial adviser field is particularly sensitive to red flags in your background. Depending on how long you have looked, and what you have tried, you might have concluded that this field is unfortunately now off-limits to you.

If so, you need to find a field for which you are qualified where your background is less impactful.

Comment: The same goes for many white-collar professions. In engineering, you often need a P.Eng., to pass PE/FE exams, graduate from an ABET accredited university in engineering or applied science, and *must demonstrate that you are a person of good character and reputation*. No one wants a potential criminal responsible for the lives and/or livelihood of clients.

Answer (score 2):

When you say you can't get a job do you mean you got accepted into a job and then failed because of your background? Or do you mean you are worried you might not get a job because of your background?

Financial field normally requires good character (read someone without a background). 30 years is a long time and generally ignored unless it was a very serious crime. However, the recent 2012 one is fairly new and depending on what it is, might be bad for you. Always be honest about it. When you get to a job interview, explain you have a background, and explain what the crime was. Express your concerns and perhaps whoever is listening to it might give you a second chance since they feel you are being honest with them and depending on what the crime was.

Remember a background check is normally conducted to see if you have reasons to do something bad, like steal money. If you are taking care of what you are doing, then that might help you in showing that while you slipped and messed up, you are owning your problems.

In all though we really can't tell you what might happen. There's no way to "hide" what you did and asking to conceal it might backfire on you, badly.

Edit: I should also add that some big banks tend to do a credit check at some interval. I had a friend who worked in financial and he indicated to me they do a yearly credit check and they not only check bad debt, but also how much you owe (good or bad) and if you owe a certain amount, they warn/let you go unless it was for medical/emergency reasons. So watch out for that as well.

Comment: Thank you Dan. What I mean is that I have no problem getting a job (4 so far) but when they do the background check i do not "pass".

Comment: @Mark I see. You might want to post this under the law section. Depending on what state and/or country you're in, you might have certain rights as far as what you can do. If you got the job, then fail the background, you might be able to question it in some way. Or as Joe above said, you might find that a career in financial field just isn't possible.